# How to setup a proper extension development environment for Joomla 3.x?

Tags: git, joomla, xdebug, development-environment, joomla-extensions

My goal is to setup a proper development environment using Ubuntu 16.04 to build Joomla extensions.

Until now I've just been zipping my extension and reinstalling it. That should drive anyone crazy.

As I sometimes also want to debug using Xdebug and I want to directly view the effect of my code changes I thought it would be nice to develop the extension directly inside the Joomla installation directory and then copy it back again to an extension.

I've read  https://docs.joomla.org/Extension_development_using_eclipse_and_phing.

They use Phing there as a build tool and propose some example build scripts for both development directions (from extension to Joomla installation directory and vice versa).

Then I found this Git repository:
https://github.com/enav/phing-joomla-extension-builder. Which works and seems to be usable in tandem with Git.

Still, I'd like to know if someone already has come up with a more efficient and proven development environment?

Or maybe someone has some pointers for creating a sane development environment? I'm open to suggestions.

For anyone looking for the part about the file permissions issue: as suggested in the comments I've split up this question and placed it here:

[How to make file permissions and file ownership stick?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46852847/694400)